# GDPR and Google Translate

Tags: google-translate

are there any detailed information on Google Translate and the GDPR?

In my opinion, translating personal data with the google translate widget is an big issue here, especially if you run an online-store and the user translates pages while checking out (i.e.: last checkout step, where all the personal data including cart-positions, billing-information and user contact-information are preset).

There is a way the exclude parts of the website from being translated (adding "notranslate" class attribute), but i assume the data itself is send to google translate servers anyway?

Looking forward to an answer.

Best regards,
Andrea

Comment: Nice question. If site administrator uses google translate on visitor's data it could be your problem which you would need to solve. But when user/visitor uses Google translate on your checkout page it is his problem, right? (I mean it is him who leaks the data but not you). So legally you should not care about it much.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, but yet, I had not actual answer to my actual question

Comment: The purpose of StackOverflow is to collect great pairs of questions and answers about software development  for future visitors to find answers easily.Your question sounds to me like **"Is using of notranslate class prevent from data being transmitted to google server?"**. I do not see how this question is related to software development directly. I think you will get better chances for the answer at [Webmasters community](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/). Also you can hook into translate process directly to get your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Collect some statistics about your visitors and implement localization for major languages they use.

This will **probably** prevent users from using google translate for your checkout process.